# How to count the number of columns in a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to count the number of columns in a table using SQL?

I am using Oracle 11g

Please help.
t.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506176/number-of-columns

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
select count(*) 
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='MYTABLE' --use upper case
```

Instead of uppercase you can use lower function.
Ex:
 select count(*) from user_tab_columns where lower(table_name)='table_name';

Comment: nothing has there in table user_tab_columns

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: It worked but the table name is case sensitive.

Comment: Is there a column that identifies the schema? What if there are two tables with the same name in different schema -- which one would 'user_table_columns' show?

Comment: Nvm -- just realize that should use 'all_tab_columns' in that case

Answer (score 10):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'FOO'
```

this will count number of columns in a the table FOO

You can also just

```
select count(*) from all_tab_columns where owner='BAR' and table_name='FOO';
```

where the owner is schema and note that Table Names are upper case

Comment: If i need not only count value but also particular column value, is it possible to append it easily?

Answer (score 8):

Old question - but I recently needed this along with the row count... here is a query for both - sorted by row count desc:

```
SELECT t.owner, 
       t.table_name, 
       t.num_rows, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   all_tables t 
       LEFT JOIN all_tab_columns c 
              ON t.table_name = c.table_name 
WHERE  num_rows IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY t.owner, 
          t.table_name, 
          t.num_rows 
ORDER  BY t.num_rows DESC;
```