# How to Count Total No.of Columns of a Table(I am in Oracle 10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

As we can count total no.of rows like select count(*) from table
Thanks

Comment: this is a question that has been asked before
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084400/how-to-count-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-using-sql

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data dictionary.  Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM all_tab_columns 
 WHERE owner = <<owner of the table>>
   AND table_name = <<name of the table>>
```

This assumes that the code/ session has `SELECT` access on the table in question.  If the table is in your schema, you could use `user_tab_columns` instead and omit the `owner`.  If you want to view the columns of tables you don't have access to, you could use `dba_tab_columns` instead but then you'd need additional privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT (column_name)
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Someone posted this identical answer 5 minutes before you and a flaw has been pointed out... there's no need to post in these circumstances.