# Table with columns TABLE_NAME and NUMBER_COLUMNS in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database that has a number of tables. I am being asked to generate a table with metadata about these tables, more precisely, I need a table with columns TABLE_NAME (where each row shows the name of a table) and NUMBER_COLUMNS (where each row shows the number of columns in that table).

I am getting the info on the table names from ALL_TABLES but I can't find a way to associate or even *find* the number of columns for each table. The methods that I've seen, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084400/how-to-count-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-using-sql), only give me a row with the cumulative number of tables.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select table_name, owner, count(*) as Number_Columns
from all_tab_cols
group by table_name, owner;
```

Comment: Probably want to group by owner and table_name if dealing with all_tab_cols in case there is a table with the same name in different schemas.