# count number of columns in a table in Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I have tried to look up the answer to my question and tried it in my php file, however so far I am not able to get the count from trying the function I saw that might have worked for other
[Number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506176/number-of-columns)
[How to count the number of columns in a table using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084400/how-to-count-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-using-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
        $tableName = $_POST['TableName'];
       
        $result = executePlainSQL("SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = " . "'{$tableName}'");
        $countTotColumn = executePlainSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tab_columns 
        where table_name = '{$tableName}'");
```

when I tried to echo to see what is inside the variable countTotColumn:

echo "The total Number of attribute is: {$countTotColumn}";

I got this:

The total Number of attribute is: Resource id #6

which is really strange. Could someone suggests a cause of this?

thank you

Comment: I believe the issue is that $countTotColumn is a result object not the integer result.

Comment: More importantly, though, your code is susceptible to SQL injection attack.  You shouldn't blindly trust strings that come in as POST values.  A user could post a value starting with a single quote and a semicolon followed by whatever evil SQL they might want to run on your database.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, the OP's code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks and they should **NEVER** build queries using template strings or string concatenation (and, instead, should use a parameterised query and bind variables). However, no, you cannot pass "a single quote and a semi-colon followed by whatever evil SQL" as Oracle forbids multiple SQL statements in a single command so your suggestion would just raise an error in Oracle (although on other RDBMS it would be valid) but there are [other things you can do instead](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/252475/261465).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following to avoid SQL injection:

```
$tableName = $_POST['TableName'];

// setup the SQL query for parameter use
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as col_count FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = :tableName";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

// bind the parameter
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":tableName", $tableName);

// run the query
oci_execute($stmt);

// get the result
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    echo $row['COL_COUNT'] . "<br>";
}

// Clean up
oci_free_statement($stmt);
```